# how can i set width to image automatically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm in the process of doing a modal photo gallery. To make things work out well, I need to set height or width to 100% depends on whether one length is bigger than the other. Adding a class contains a height set is working, but is a small problem with width. It doesn't work for this! Help

Here is jquery

```
    $(function() {
    if($('.modal-img').height() > $('.modal-img').width()) {
     $('.modal-img').addClass('set-height');
    }
      else if($('.modal-img').height() < $('.modal-img').width()) {
      $('.modal-img').addClass('set-width');
    }
    else {
       $('.modal-img').addClass('set-height');
       $('.modal-img').addClass('set-width');
    }
    });
```

Can you help? please. I do not know if it's because I set the position: absolute to these images, but i hope not.

Comment: Can you share a codepen or fiddle demonstrating? Not sure I understand exactly what your set up is

Comment: Yeah please provide an example on jsfiddle or something, I don't know exactly what you mean

Comment: here you go https://codepen.io/kolosowski/pen/BdXERa

Comment: I don't know why this script doesnt work here. Maybe on site codepen doesn't work. on my local sources working.

Comment: I want my script to work like this:
keeping height or width always on 100%.
I want to solve this this way:
If any axis are smaller than the other one - set this on 100%.
Simply but i dont how to make it correctly.